# How to Extract hyperlinks and tun it into active clickable links without me clicking twise on cell?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a set of websites listed in column A, I need a macro code to extract hyperlinks in the column B without me clicking twise on the cell to make the hyperlink active (I tried some codesthat I found on  the internet, but all of them were just extracting the inactive hyperlinks untill I double click on the cell to activate it). so the code should extracts and activates in the same time the hyperlinks from column A into column B. Would that be possible?
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqfvJqj0Eub6dOL096GecliFC4c?e=BPapgc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

No need for VBA to do this.
You could simply write a formula in column B:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1)
```

[image]